# PHP Get the most popular item in table

Tags: php, mysql

lets say that my table looks like:

```
username userid
a1       1
a1       1
a1       1
b2       2
c2       3
d2       3
```

the most popular username:`a1`

How do I find the most popular item in table?

Comment: what you consider popular the item that was quired the most, updated the most

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT username, count(*) AS frequency
FROM your_table
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 1
```

would yield a single row:

```
username | frequency
---------+----------
a1         3
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` -> `LIMIT 5`. (In the kindest way possible, may I politely suggest that you RTFM about SQL?)